# How to see the source code of macro button

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkdJo.png)[image: see this pic]

I want see the source code of that particular macro button which is provided in image, is there any way to see the source code of each and every macro button like that

Thanks for your answer ☺️

Comment: That's not a *macro button*. It's a toolbar button, and it's source is not written in VBA, and is not available. It's part of Excel itself.

Answer (score 1):

To discover the VBA methods that using Excel's combine toolbar button triggers, start recording a macro, giving the macro a name like "discover_combine_vba." If you've never recorded or looked at the code for a macro before, this [MS Excel article shows how](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45#:%7E:text=The%20Developer%20tab%20isn%27t,select%20the%20Developer%20check%20box.)

Once you have a macro recording, press the "Combine" button and combine your data sources in a configuration that interests you. Once complete, stop the macro recording. Then you can open the VBA Editor Window with ALT+F11, find your "discover_combine_vba" macro, and see what VBA code was being executed as you utilized the PowerQuery Combine features.